# Can magic items be combined, and how many at once?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I've been looking into making a Master of Many Forms, but I've run into two issues with this; you're both naked and unarmed. Now, when turning into something like a Beholder or a T. rex this is not much of an issue, but when turning into a (monstrous) humanoid, a Giant or a Fey this creates some problems. Even with the strength of a giant, it is more preferable to hit someone with a big sword instead of your fists. And because there are no mechanical benefits to charging at someone naked, even if you happen to be a Storm Giant or something like that, clothes are also wanted.

First off is clothes. The obvious combination is a Vestment of Many Styles (RoE) with a Wildling Clasp (MIC), so you can keep it when you Wild Shape. The thing is, this is just regular clothing that gives no AC or something like that. The [Master of Many Forms Bible](http://community.wizards.com/comment/13077376#comment-13077376) makes reference to combining magical items together at additional cost, but it makes no mention of where to find these rules. So my first question is:

**Is it possible to make combinations of magical items, and if so how many onto a single item?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for creating custom magic items are in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, table 7-33 and nearby pages.
On page 288, under the Adding New Abilities header, are the rules you need for adding (you guessed it) new abilities to existing magic items.

A Wild armor/shield (Racede of Stone) is subsumed into your new form but the armor/shield bonus stays. It can be used in conjunction with a tunic, so you don't go around naked. My MoMF used to drop a big blanket on the ground before morphing into some giant form, using it as a peplum. Unless you need to morph during battle, I found it to be an ok way to manage nudity.

As an alternative, Beastskin Armor (MIC, p. 7) uses wildshape charges to change shape with you. MoMF gains lots of WS uses, so the solution is viable as long as you don't change shape too often.

Answer (score 2):

Magic Item Compendium has rules for combining effects of multiple magic items, with the only caveats being cost (+50% cost of the more expensive item/effect, unless it has a price listed under the table of common effects on p.234) and slot limitations (can only combine effects of items that occupy the same body slot).